Polynomials are dense in $X$
I am working on a functional analysis homework question

Consider the normed space $X=\{f|f\in C[0,1] \text{and} \|f\|<\infty\}$ where $\|f\|=\max_{0\le t\le 1}|f(t)|+\sup_{0<s<t<1}{|f(t)-f(s)|\over \sqrt{t-s}}$. Prove or disprove that the set of polynomials is dense in X

I have attempted to use the Weierstrass approximation theorem, I still have no idea how to  deal with the term $\sup_{0<s<t<1}{|f(t)-f(s)|\over \sqrt{t-s}}$. Can someone give me some ideas what to do?

You are essentially asking whether polynomials are dense in the $1/2$-Holder normed space. This was asked before in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360537/polynomials-not-dense-in-holder-spaces?rq=1.

The first answer has hints how to tackle this.
